# Converting Datatype "object" to "Float"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been working with a CSV file for the last few days. And What I want is to convert data into float format in CSV in order to round up the last few digits after the decimal point. When I ran Dataframe **"dtypes"** on a pandas data frame, it turns out the data is neither float or integer. The type of data was **object** shown in the figure below :

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot that few numeric data is in Object format. So I want to know that, how to convert object type to float in python.

Any Information on this will appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: series = [series.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)

Comment: please edit your post with the code as text; not an image.

Comment: pandas uses object dtype when the series contains strings or other things that can't be numbers.  Numbers in those columns might be strings, but they could also be python numbers (but not numpy array values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else already answered the question in the comments with .astype() … but here is some code to explain it.

Just as a pro tip, please provide starter code to create a sample dataframe to make it easier for people to help you.

```py
import pandas as pd

# step 1: create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'strain': ['10.123456789', '10.23456789', '10.3456789'],
                   'temp': ['1.7', '1.8', '1.9'],
                   'weight': ['100.4', '100.5', '100.6'],
                  })

# step 2: examine dataframe and dtypes
print('Dataframe: ')
print(df.head())
print()
print('Dtypes: ')
print(df.dtypes)
print()

# step 3: convert the 'strain' column to float, round to 2 decimal places
df['strain_float'] = df['strain'].astype(float).round(2)

# step 4: examine dataframe and dtypes
print('Dataframe: ')
print(df.head())
print()
print('Dtypes: ')
print(df.dtypes)
print()
df
```

[image]